# Mysql Query convert to Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

## I have this code in mysql

> how to use this code in codeigniter

```
SELECT * FROM `bulan` WHERE id_bulan NOT IN (SELECT id_bulan from pembayaran_spp WHERE id_siswa = '18')
```

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. What have you tried, show us your attempt and we'll go from there. NB: We are not a free coding service, just a help forum

Comment: "how to use this code in codeigniter" By reading the current version manual. https://www.codeigniter.com/docs search for "Query Builder Class".

Comment: you can use this code. $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM `bulan` WHERE id_bulan NOT IN (SELECT id_bulan from pembayaran_spp WHERE id_siswa = '18')
');

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split this query - and use the `get_compiled_select` method, because i'm pretty sure your `id_siswa` is dynamic  and should get protected from sql injections.

Something like the following should work

```
$id = 18;

$strSubquery = $this->db
    ->select('id_bulan')
    ->from('pembayaran_spp')
    ->where('id_siswa', $id)
    ->get_compiled_select();


$query = $this->db
    ->from('bulan')
    ->where_not_in('id_bulan', $strSubquery, false)
    ->get();

print_r($query->result());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
$result = $this->db->where_not_in('id_bulan', 'SELECT id_bulan from pembayaran_spp WHERE id_siswa = "18"', FALSE)
         ->get('bulan')->result();
print_r($result);
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html